# Solution for Gmail Email Blast

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Why: I'm a parent-teacher organization chairperson responsible for email communication to a community of 750 to 1,000. We switched to Gmail recently to save money.

What I do: I split my distribution list into groups of less than 250 people each. I write one email and then copy/paste the contents into multiple others. I place my distribution groups into each email BCC line and click send on each of the multiple emails.

What I'd like to do: Write one email and send without exceeding the per-email limit. Perhaps a google script can help? I've been looking at mail merge scripts, but they seem to be built for one at a email send at a time. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have a Google Apps for Business account, you are limited to 500 recipients per day for a script (For Business account it is 1500 per day). I'm not sure what mail-merge script you've been using so its hard to tell what you can change to suit your requirement. Can you post some code of the script you've already used. 
Since you're new, I also suggest you go through the SO checklist for posting a question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Thanks Srik. I am not using a code at all right now -- and I'm only sending 4 or 5 emails at this point with about 250 in each -- google says I can have up to 500 recipients per email (http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852), but I keep it to about 250 each to avoid issues.I was just looking at the mail merge options to see if anything would work. I was thinking maybe I could just keep sending multiple emails with groups of email addresses on the bcc line, but somehow automate it so I don't have to copy/paste the message every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use google groups. Will solve all your issues plus you will write a single email.
I think you can do it with a gmail admin account. If not buy a google spps domain for a single user and do it from there.

Comment: Zig, that's a brilliant idea. I'm curious though. If I go with groups, does each member need to sign up with their email or can I do a bulk import?

Comment: You can add them yourself as group admin. Ive only used them from a gapps domain (not gmail) and on that context you can add them directly as members instead of just inviting them.

Comment: However users can configure their group email options so they might not get an instant email like they do now.